# Magento2: The env.php file keeps automatically changing

Tags: magento2, full-page-cache, server-setup, deploy, environment-variable

The file env.php is changing automatically and randomly.

Environment:

Cluster server

Deployer

Magento 2.4.6-p3

Redis, varnish and cloudflare

php 8.1

Here is the actual the env.php

```
    'session' => [
    'save' => 'db',
    'gc_probability' => 1,
    'gc_divisor' => 1000,
    'gc_maxlifetime' => 7200
],
'cache_types' => [
    'config' => 1,
    'layout' => 1,
    'block_html' => 1,
    'collections' => 1,
    'reflection' => 1,
    'db_ddl' => 1,
    'compiled_config' => 1,
    'eav' => 1,
    'customer_notification' => 1,
    'config_integration' => 1,
    'config_integration_api' => 1,
    'google_product' => 1,
    'full_page' => 1,
    'config_webservice' => 1,
    'translate' => 1,
    'vertex' => 1,
    'fishpig_wordpress' => 1
],
'http_cache_hosts' => [
    [
        'host' => 'xx.xxx.x.xx',
        'port' => 'yyyy'
    ],
    [
        'host' => 'xx.xxx.x.xx',
        'port' => 'yyyy'
    ]
],
```

On a random time of the day and randomly the env.php changes to this:

```
'session' => [
    'save' => 'Redis'
],
'cache_types' => [
    'config' => 1,
    'layout' => 1,
    'block_html' => 1,
    'collections' => 1,
    'reflection' => 1,
    'db_ddl' => 1,
    'compiled_config' => 1,
    'eav' => 1,
    'customer_notification' => 1,
    'config_integration' => 1,
    'config_integration_api' => 1,
    'google_product' => 1,
    'full_page' => 0,
    'config_webservice' => 1,
    'translate' => 1,
    'vertex' => 1,
    'fishpig_wordpress' => 1
],
'http_cache_hosts' => [
    [
        'host' => '127.0.0.1',
        'port' => '8080'
    ]
],
```

what has been changes is session, full_page, and http_cache_host.

Does anyone encountered a similar issue? what could be the cause of this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Did you commit the file app/etc/env.php from your dev machine to your repo?

That file shouldn't be in your repository because it'll be different for each environment.

Tom

Comment: Hi Tom, I have the env.php in the .gitignore, I mean the file does not change upon doing pull from the repository.

Answer (score 0):

Your Server setup have auto deployment system. I mean CICD or container jenkins system, if yes then you have to check container setup etc.

Comment: No there is no auto deployment system.

Comment: Can you connect with me real time so that i will analyse and let you know. my skype id is puneetak4 and phone whatsapp number is 9891472590